# What happens when you increase the size of a struct in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, offset

A problem I'm working on involves a large tree structure. Initially I was creating the tree by `new`ing new nodes and attaching them to their parent node and such. This was taking an awful long time. A friend suggested instead I forgo the dynamic memory allocation and structure the tree as an array with offsets to child words. I've not done this before and so I have some questions about what actually happens.

Here's the ultra basic, no safety checks on anything example:

```
struct DataStructure
{
    std::vector<Entry> mCollection;
};

struct Entry
{
    char mValue;
    std::vector<unsigned int> mOffsetCollection; //a vector of indexes that are offsets to other entries.
};
```

I'm curious about what happens as I add more data to this structure. If I added

```
DataStructure d;
Entry entry;
entry.mValue = 'a';
d.push_back(entry);
.
.
.//add some more entries...
.
.
//now suppose I add a bunch of offsets to these various entries in my array.
Entry& firstEntry = d.at(0);
firstEntry.mOffsetCollection.push_back(4);
firstEntry.mOffsetCollection.push_back(9);
firstEntry.mOffsetCollection.push_back(32);
..
```

So the size of this first Entry is increasing. What exactly happens? I just ran through through a small example and it seemed to work fine. The other entries in the data structure were unaffected. I was initially concerned that perhaps if the size of the structure became large it would run into the next item in the array but I suppose that isn't happening. It makes me realize that I don't really know what is going on behind the scenes. Is the `vector<Entry>` in `DataStructure d` having to reallocate memory?

Comment: "size of the structure became large it would run into the next item in the array" ... What array? You have a vector object, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using dynamic allocation, but the vector class is. The internal `vector<int>` is storing its variable-length array externally to the Entry object that you're putting in the outer vector.

Comment: Ok yeah this makes sense. I was thinking that a vector stores in contiguous memory and wasn't sure how this worked beyond the simple example of say, storing ints.

Comment: A vector does store its array in contiguous memory -- that's pointed to by the vector object. You can exploit this guarantee in code by passing pointers to vector elements to functions expecting an array.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a `std::vector` dynamically manages its own memory.

The size of a struct (indeed, any data type) is fixed at compile time; it is not affected at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

The size of a `std::vector` is constant, as it stores data using pointers to heap blocks internally, generally it has a begin, end and current pointer, and not much else, making it pretty small as well.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem nit-picky, but your choice of verbiage threw me off and I suspect it might be throwing you off as well...

> What happens when you increase the
>   size of a struct in a vector?

Keep in mind that the size of the `struct` *itself* never changes, nor can any struct ever change in size at runtime.

If you do `sizeof(DataStructure)` at the beginning of the program, then push a bunch of stuff back and do `sizeof(DataStructure)` again, the results will be exactly the same.  This is because the data you're pushing back isn't *part* of `DataStructure` iself, but is *pointed to* by something in `DataStructure`.

Where are the pointers I'm talking about?  In the `vector`.  `vector` also never changes size -- but the number of items within it does.  `vector` manages a pointer to some dynamically-allocated array of stuff that you're pushing back.  As you push back more stuff, the managed array fills up.  When the managed array is finally full to `capacity()`, the `vector` has to allocate a new, bigger array and copy your stuff in to it (which is why STL-contained objects must be "copyable").

Comment: I'm really happy you brought up this point because I just assumed that the struct did change size. I hadn't actually done a `sizeof(DataStructure)` to check. I suppose then if you actually wanted to know the size at any moment you would have to roll through every element in the DataStructure and sum the `sizeof()`'s of all its data members?